# Cant get 15.04 or 14.10 or any version of Ubuntu to boot on Flex 10

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.10, uefi, 15.04

I've seen a few questions around bit no one has really been able to hope. Ive been trying to get 64bit Linux working on this laptop through its 32bit EFI every nown and again for about a year now and have been unable to. I have followed guides all over the place for bay trail devices but whatever I do I have a black screen after the grub menu. No matter what i set in options, be it nomodeset or booting to terminal it instantly goes to a black screen with the backlight on and no activity at all, keyboard locked ( caps lock light wont even go on ).

I've tried guides for both 14.10 and 15.04 and 14.04. Ive seen people around who have made it work on their flex 10 but mine just seems to not work. Mine is a slightly different model and has a N3510 instead of the normal CPU.

Was wondering if anyone can give me some more commands to try or perhaps suggest how I try some different kernels or something to make this boot. Forget desktop, Id be happy getting terminal running on this thing, without having to resort to a 32bit image though :P

Thanks for any help